# How to use jQuery to show images like video

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html

I would like to use a plugin similar to cycle to take images, and treat them more like a video. It would do a little bit of scroll/pan/tilt/zoom(in/out) for a few seconds on the image and then fade to the next image. I can't find anything even remotely close to this, but it seems like just the thing jQuery is built for.

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no one single plug-in that does what your asking for.  You would either use jQuery with a bit of you own code, or a combination of pre-existing plug-ins.  Either way you would have to write some code your self or have some one write for you.  Lately i've been looking for a plug-in that runs an ecommerce website myself, couldn't find one.  Happy Holidays ;)

Comment: You should answer your own question; it's not ideal, but it beats leaving your question "unanswered" forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/