# Display images like a video

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page - c# -. I have, say 20 images in a directory in my web application. All the images are the same size.  I would like to display these images as a movie clip without converting them to a video.  What is the best way to do this?  Should I use a repeater to store these images (and hide this control?). Or should I use AJAX methods to render these images?  I envisage putting a Thread.Sleep between images to control frame rate.

What is the possible ramifications of doing this (aka stream of images and not a mp4 file)? Does this mean all images would have to be downloaded/included in the asp.net (and rendered to HTML) to the clients browser?

Any info will be great.

Thanks

Comment: use jquery image gallery http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. that site certainly looks impressive. I am struggling to find an appropriate example to suit my needs. Did you see 1 in particular that suited my needs?  Sorry to be so dense...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery to show images like video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521699/how-to-use-jquery-to-show-images-like-video)

Comment: Hi, thank you both.  I am now looking at converting my images to a sprite and displaying in a div using an offset mechanism.